# DAX - Inserting value into table from other table based on condition

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-modeling, calculated-columns, tabular

I have two tables:

Table A (A simple 3 line table):

| Year | Objective |
| --- | --- |
| 2021 | 2 |
| 2022 | 3 |
| 2023 | 3.5 |

Table B:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 10/09/2021 | 23 |
| 30/10/2021 | 24.4 |
| 22/05/2022 | 34 |
| 10/09/2022 | 23 |
| 11/03/2023 | 23.6 |
| 23/09/2023 | 27 |
| ect... | ect... |

There is no relationship between these two tables.

What I need is a calculated column in Table B that will show the tableA.Objective based on if tableA.Year is equal to the year of TableB.Date. Like so:

| Date | Value | My calculated column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/09/2021 | 23 | 2 |
| 30/10/2021 | 24.4 | 2 |
| 22/05/2022 | 34 | 3 |
| 10/09/2022 | 23 | 3 |
| 11/03/2023 | 23.6 | 3.5 |
| 23/09/2023 | 27 | 3.5 |
| etc... | etc... | etc... |

However, I don't know how to create such a calculated column. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Extract year from Table B. Use dax function `lookupvalue` to populate Objective column in Table B from Table A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ashok suggested,

```
My calculated column = LOOKUPVALUE(TableA[Objective], TableA[Year], YEAR(TableB[Date]))
```